# Long Spring Framework JMS Client Timeout On Broker Restart

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I have a test JMS client application that uses [`JmsTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) to send, and [`DefaultMessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) to receive.

The application sends a single message to a queue, and then reads that message from the queue. It does this once a second. Think of it as a "periodic ping" to the broker. My goal is to use this to detect and report the ability to "ping the broker". In this context when the broker is down, I want the ping to fail within a configurable time period (e.g. 2 seconds).

When the system is healthy the typical "ping time" takes about 96 msec.
[image]

I then kill and restart the broker and expect the client ping to fail, it does. However the call to `convertAndSend` takes a very long time to return (15 to 21 seconds). This is much greater than my goal of 2 seconds.

The 15 second timeout can be seen here:
[image]

Notice in particular the two exceptions that are caught. The first one (underlined in yellow) is caught by the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. The second one (underlined in red) is one thrown by `convertAndSend` (caught in pol, see `TrackedBroker.poll` method in code below).

Once the broker is back (up and running) the "pinger" application again periodically pings the broker in the "healthy system"fashion.

In my current implementation the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, and the `JmsTemplate` each use their own pooling connection factory. As the connectionFactory construction method (seen below) suggests, I have attempted to configure the factory to shorten the length of timeouts. It would seem that the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` is blocking for 15 seconds.

I am looking for suggestions on how to shorten the ping failure timeout from 15 to 2.

I'd prefer to let spring do as much as possible in terms of connection lifecycle management. I only started to muck with things like timeouts, when I was trying to solve this problem. I've dug through spring JMS documentation on JMSTemplate and on DefaultMessageListenerContainer, however because the management of the connection lifecycle to a JMS broker is not simple, its difficult to understand exactly how to resolve this problem.

The following is the code that I am currently using:

`TrackedBroker`

```
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ActiveMQClient;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientSessionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ServerLocator;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.util.backoff.FixedBackOff;

import javax.jms.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class TrackedBroker implements MessageListener, ErrorHandler {
    private int POLL_ATTEMPT_FAIL_THRESHOLD = 3;
    private boolean alive = false;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int pollAttempt = POLL_ATTEMPT_FAIL_THRESHOLD;
    private int sequenceNumber = 0;
    JmsTemplate template;
    MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer;
    String url;
    String user;
    String password;
    String brokerEndpoint;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TrackedBroker.class);
    public TrackedBroker(AppConfig.Broker b, String brokerEndpoint) {

        this.name = b.getName();
        this.user = b.getUser();
        this.password = b.getPassword();
        this.brokerEndpoint = brokerEndpoint;
        this.description = b.getDescription();

        String url = "tcp://"+b.getHost()+":"+b.getPort();
        this.url = url;
    }

    private  MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(String url, String user, String pw, String brokerEndpoint) throws JMSException {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.initialize();


        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory(url, user, pw));
        container.setDestinationName(brokerEndpoint);
        container.setReceiveTimeout(1000);
        //container.setConcurrency("4");
        //container.setConcurrentConsumers(10);
        FixedBackOff backoff = new FixedBackOff(200,  FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS);
        container.setBackOff(backoff);
        container.setRecoveryInterval(100);
        container.setMessageListener(this);
        container.setErrorHandler(this);

        return container;
    }
    
    private  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(String url, String user, String pw) throws JMSException{
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setPreAcknowledge(true);
        connectionFactory.setBlockOnAcknowledge(false);
        connectionFactory.setBlockOnNonDurableSend(false);
        connectionFactory.setCallTimeout(500);
        connectionFactory.setCallFailoverTimeout(500);
        connectionFactory.setClientFailureCheckPeriod(500);
        connectionFactory.setCallFailoverTimeout(400);
        //connectionFactory.setConnectionTTL(3000);


        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(url);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(pw);
        connectionFactory.setUser(user);
        CachingConnectionFactory caching_connection_factory = new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        return caching_connection_factory;
    }
    
    private  JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(String url, String user, String pw) throws JMSException{

        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory(url, user, pw));
        template.setDeliveryPersistent(false);

        //template.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);


        return template;
    }    

    public void init() throws JMSException  {
        setTemplate(jmsTemplate(url, user, password));
        setMessageListenerContainer(listenerContainer(url, user, password, brokerEndpoint));
        getMessageListenerContainer().start();
    }

    public void sendMessage(JmsTemplate jmsTmpl, String message) {

        String label1 = "Broker Convert & Send" + getName();
        Date date1 = DeltaLogger.logStart(label1);

        jmsTmpl.convertAndSend(brokerEndpoint, message);

        DeltaLogger.logEnd(label1, date1);
    }

    public void poll() {
        incrementPollAttempt();
        incrementSequenceNumber();
        String probeMsg = "Probe Broker " + getName() + " Yo " + getSequenceNumber();
        try {
            String label1 = "Broker Send" + getName();
            Date date1 = DeltaLogger.logStart(label1);
            sendMessage(getTemplate(), probeMsg);
            DeltaLogger.logEnd(label1, date1);
        } catch (UncategorizedJmsException e) {
            log.error("JMS Exception " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        log.info("My current poll attempts " + getName() + ": " + getPollAttempt());
        if(getPollAttempt() > POLL_ATTEMPT_FAIL_THRESHOLD) {
            setAlive(false);
        } else {
            setAlive(true);
        }
    }


    public boolean isAlive() {
        return alive;
    }

    private void setAlive(boolean alive) {
        this.alive = alive;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    private void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPollAttempt() {
        return pollAttempt;
    }

    private void setPollAttempt(int pollAttempt) {
        this.pollAttempt = pollAttempt;
    }

    private void incrementPollAttempt() {
        this.pollAttempt++;
    }

    private void clearPollAttempt() {
        this.pollAttempt = 0;
    }

    public JmsTemplate getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    private void setTemplate(JmsTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    private void setSequenceNumber(int sequenceNumber) {
        this.sequenceNumber = sequenceNumber;
    }

    public int getSequenceNumber() {
        return sequenceNumber;
    }

    private void incrementSequenceNumber() {
        this.sequenceNumber++;
    }

    public MessageListenerContainer getMessageListenerContainer() {
        return messageListenerContainer;
    }

    private void setMessageListenerContainer(MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer) {
        this.messageListenerContainer = messageListenerContainer;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    private void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                String text = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                log.info("Received " + text);
                clearPollAttempt();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable throwable) {
        log.error("Error" + throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

I currently load the following configuration (`configprops.json`):

```
{
  "brokers": [
    {"name": "artemis0", "description": "tonga", "host": "10.93.97.202", "port":  32192, "user": "artemis", "password": "aaa"},
    {"name": "artemis1", "description": "spain", "host": "10.93.103.236", "port":  32192, "user": "artemis", "password": "aaa"}
  ]
}
```

`JsonPropertySourceFactory`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.saab.ims.smart_proxy.controller.ScheduledTasks;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;


public class JsonPropertySourceFactory
        implements PropertySourceFactory {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonPropertySourceFactory.class);
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(
            String name, EncodedResource resource)
            throws IOException {

        Map readValue = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(resource.getInputStream(), Map.class);


        return  new MapPropertySource("json-property", readValue);
    }
}
```

`AppConfig`

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@PropertySource(
        value = "classpath:configprops.json",
        factory = JsonPropertySourceFactory.class)
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);
    private int port;
    private boolean resend;
    private String host;


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    public void setResend(boolean resend) {
        this.resend = resend;
    }

    public boolean isResend() {
        return resend;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    private List<String> topics;

    public List<String> getTopics() {
        return topics;
    }

    public void setTopics(List<String> topics) {
        this.topics = topics;
    }


    private  List<Broker> brokers ;

    public List<Broker> getBrokers() {
        return  mapper.convertValue(brokers,
                new TypeReference<List<Broker>>(){});
    }

    public void setBrokers(List<Broker> brokers) {
        log.info("Broker is " + brokers);
        this.brokers = brokers;
    }

    public static class Broker {
        private String name;
        private String description;
        private String host;
        private int port;
        private String user;
        private String password;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public String getHost() {
            return host;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return port;
        }

        public String getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(String user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }

}
```

`ScheduledTasks`

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;


@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    private long probeBrokerCnt = 0;
    private long probeProxyCnt = 0;

    private ArrayList<TrackedBroker> trackedBrokerList = new ArrayList<TrackedBroker>();

    @Autowired
    DispatcherService dispatcherService;

    @Autowired
    HaProxyService haproxyService;

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        List<AppConfig.Broker> brokerList =appConfig.getBrokers();

        for(int i = 0; i < brokerList.size(); i++) {

            AppConfig.Broker b = brokerList.get(i);
            log.info("My cool broker " + b.getName() +
                    " Host " + b.getHost() + " Port " + b.getPort() +
                    " User " + b.getUser() + " PW " + b.getPassword());

            TrackedBroker tb = new TrackedBroker(b, "Q.Proxy.Probe");

            try {
                tb.init();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                log.error("Failed to create JMS Template " + e);
            }

            trackedBrokerList.add(tb);

        }
    }


    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void probeBroker() {
        Date date1 = new Date();
        log.info("Starting Probe ");
        for(TrackedBroker tb : trackedBrokerList) {
            tb.poll();
            log.info("Broker " + tb.getName() + " Desc " + tb.getDescription() + " Alive " + Boolean.toString(tb.isAlive()));
        }
        Date date2 = new Date();
        long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        log.info("Ending Probe- Duration(seconds): " + Double.toString(difference/1000.0));
        //dispatcherService.sendMessage(probeMsg);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing everything yourself? You are bypassing Spring here, calling the lifecycle methods (in the wrong place even) etc. Why don't you let Spring configure the `ConnectionFactory` and other infrastructure components?

Comment: @M.Deinum I'd prefer to let spring do as much as possible. I only started to muck with things like timeouts, when I was trying to solve this problem. If you can be more explicit about the specific changes I might make to allow spring to manage the lifecycle in a fashion that will allow me to achieve the configurable timeout goal (e.g. 2 seconds), then awesome. Though I have a ton of experience with Java, I have minimal experience with Spring, and relatively minimal experience with JMS.  Please advise.

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind, is that I actually use the application to ping mulitple "TrackedBrokers". It does this just fine, except for this one problem related to shortening the timeout when a broker is restarted.

Comment: Let Spring create all the beans (and thus the lifecycle). You can create a reuseable configuration class to do so. However one thing that is glaringly obvious is that you are calling `initialize` on the `DefaultListenerContainer` right after construction, so setting the other parameters is useless as it is already created. But if you let Spring manage this thing it will call the methods in the right time. But isn't it just enough to get the connection and create a session if that fails things are broken, sending a message doesn't really add things imho.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'd like to let spring "create all the beans". However I'm not sure exactly what should be a bean, nor how to configure them. Keep in mind that I have multiple TrackedBrokers. Can you provide more guidance on how to do what you are suggesting. I'll include the configuration that I currently use to configure these TrackedBrokers

Comment: Please don't add additional code as comments, that is totally unreadable and you might want to obfuscate it (change ip, user,pwd etc).

Comment: And you are using Spring Boot, that is something you didn't tell.

Comment: I am using spring boot for as much as I can.

Comment: You are aware that Spring Boot (the actuator) already does JMS checking out-of-the-box?

Comment: @M.Deinum Sure, I'm aware of that. The most useful guidance would be a somewhat detailed suggestion on how to refactor my application (and specifically the TrackedBroker class that you see above), so that it can rely on springboot to the extent possible. I've augmented the issue above to show the key classes (as they currently exist). The key classes are the configuration class (AppConfig), and the TrackedBroker.

Comment: I've also added `ScheduledTasks` to illustrate how I configure and poll the TrackedBrokers

Comment: Is there a reason yu don't use the JMS health checks build into Spring Boot but write your own? I'll ponder a little on the question, see if I can write an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I very much appreciate you taking the time to ponder, and to suggest a solution.  The short answer to your question is ... I'm still a spring boot noobie :)
I did have an early version of this app that used the spring boot Service (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html)  to stand up a broker sender and a receiver. However I wasnt sure how to configure this with multiple brokers..

Comment: Spring Boot can automatically configure a listener and template (a single one) however you can use that to your advantage to create multiple as well by re-using those classes (much like adding multiple `DataSource` instances as explained in the Spring Boot reference guide). When doing so you and adding the Spring Boot Actuator you already have the health check (and don't need to write your own), although that only check the connection but imho that is enough you don't need the roundtrip.

Comment: Yes. I actually started with spring boots ability to automatically create a listener and a separate sender, I can include that code if it helps. However when I needed to configure multiple listeners and multiple senders (based on my json configuration, for multiple brokers), i began to refactor ... what you described was my starting point.

Comment: [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources) explains how to configure 2 datasources, you can use the same for a JMS `ConnectionFactory`. When adding those, together with the Spring Boot Actuator you already have the health check in place (I believe it configures a check per `ConnectionFactory`) and you don't need the `JmsTemplate` and listener containers.